# creating, editing and deleting a pdf-file with java

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I've been searching for a while now for a way to create, edit and delete a pdf-file with java. I found libraries like IText etc. but I have no clue how to use it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can find [plenty of handy examples on their site](http://itextpdf.com/examples). You should try them out and come up with specific questions if you hit the wall.

Comment: Apart from the examples, we also have [plenty of questions and answers](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions), so by all means go to the [developers pages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and start your developer journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but this will give you a head start:

**Create:**

The minimal iText example can be found in the [Getting Started](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/getting-started) section of the [Q&A](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions) on the official web site.

**Edit:**

As explained in the introduction of [Chapter 6 of my book](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3/3c9ca46-76da-4de2-8972-b82efbe0bf88/samplechapter6.pdf), PDF is not a *document editing format*. This doesn't mean you can't manipulate a PDF:

- You can fill out [interactive forms](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/interactive-forms) as explained in FAQ entries such as [How to fill out a pdf file programmatically?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-acroform-technology),
- You can [manipulate PDFs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/manipulating-existing-pdfs), for instance: you can [merge existing PDF documents](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents) or [stamp content on an existing document](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs).

**Delete:**

You don't need a PDF library to delete a file. The standard Java class `File` can delete any file, including a PDF file.